# can't get post parameter in multipart form

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine

I have the following form shown in a modal of a bootstrap page 
the aim is to upload a file with a hidden id
the application is based on Google App Engine, Python/Webapp2

```
<form action="someUrl" role="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="hidden" name="entityId" value="{{datastoreEntity.key.id()}}"/>
                 <input name="importFile" type="file" multiple>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly>

                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Import">


                </form>
```

the problem is in the related RequestHandler (server side) where I can retrieve the file with

```
    raw_file = self.request.POST.multi['importFile'].file
```

But I can't get the id (which is correctly generated by Jinja2 - checked in the page source). I have already tried with

```
     self.request.get('entityId')
     self.request.POST['entityId']
     self.request.POST.multi['entityId']
```

Comment: are you sure about the id? it is correctly generated and the file is posted too.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the problem as you relate it in the simplest of ways.  I've copied that template into `form.html`, direct `/` to `MainHandler`, and net of the usual preparations (imports, `jinja_environment` with a `FileLoader` in the current dir, etc, I have):

```
class It(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        dse = It(name="Willy")
        dsek = dse.put()
        datastoreEntity = dsek.get()
        template = jinja_environment.get_template('form.html')
        self.response.write(template.render(dict(
            datastoreEntity=datastoreEntity,
        )))
    def post(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain' 
        self.response.write(self.request.get('entityId'))
```

Visiting `/`, picking a file, and clicking the `Import` button, I see on my browser: 5066549580791808 -- which seems to be a typical datastore entity ID, as desired.

Please "interpolate" between this toy super-simplified version, and the no doubt much more complex things you're trying to do, and edit your Q to show us the very simplest way you can reproduce your problem, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Uploading via file inputs in App Engine requires that the app use a path that's obtained from the blobstore API. The doc for that is [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Uploading_a_blob). So you probably want to do something like

```
upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/someUrl')
```

and then inject that into your template so that the form can use it

```
<form action="{{upload_url}}" ...
```

Once the file upload is complete, blobstore will redirect to `/someUrl`, where you process the rest of the form, including `.file`.

Comment: The upload works... I just need to retrieve the entityId parameter.